# CKAN installation errors: Sites ckan_default and datapusher do not exist

Tags: python, apache, ubuntu, nginx, ckan

I am trying to install [CKAN](http://ckan.org) onto Ubuntu 13.10. (64bit) following [these instructions](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/installing/install-from-package.html). Python 2.7.5+ is installed on the machine. The following errors stop me from installing the CKAN package:

```bash
$ sudo dpkg -i python-ckan_2.2_amd64.deb
Selecting previously unselected package python-ckan.
(Reading database ... 289528 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking python-ckan (from python-ckan_2.2_amd64.deb) ...
Setting up python-ckan (2.2-1) ...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/bin/paster", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ \
    distribute-0.6.24-py2.7.egg/pkg_resources.py", line 16, in <module>
    import sys, os, zipimport, time, re, imp, types
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/re.py", line 105, in <module>
    import sre_compile
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/sre_compile.py", line 14, in <module>
    import sre_parse
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/sre_parse.py", line 17, in <module>
    from sre_constants import *
  File "/usr/lib/ckan/default/lib/python2.7/sre_constants.py", line 18, in <module>
    from _sre import MAXREPEAT

ImportError: cannot import name MAXREPEAT
 System start/stop links for /etc/init.d/nginx already exist.
 System start/stop links for /etc/init.d/apache2 already exist.
ERROR: Site ckan_default does not exist!
ERROR: Site datapusher does not exist!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, I installed CKAN from source as suggested by the [documentation](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/installing/install-from-package.html):

> This is the quickest and easiest way to install CKAN, but it requires Ubuntu 12.04 64-bit.